# Netty: Concurrency issues using multiple event loops

Tags: java, concurrency, netty

I have one client connecting to n different servers. So, i am creating n different channels.
Because my servers are more than 5000. I am using 10 event loops with only one event loop group.Also, there is separate pipeline for each channel.
I already know there would be no concurrency problem if i will use one event loop and i have not seen any concurrency problem on 10 event loops yet.My question is:
Will i will be having concurrency problem on line `healthTargets.storeHealthyTarget(InetAddress.getByName(remoteAddress));` in the below piece of code and why?
I suspect there will be a concurrency problem.Because, if multiple event loops are not accessing this, then what is the point being using multiple event loops?

```
 @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, HttpObject httpObject) throws UnknownHostException {
        if(channelHandlerContext.channel().remoteAddress() != null)
        {
            String remoteAddress = remoteAddress(channelHandlerContext.channel().remoteAddress().toString());
            if (httpObject instanceof HttpResponse) {
                HttpResponseStatus responseStatus = ((HttpResponse)httpObject).getStatus();
                if (responseStatus.code() == HttpResponseStatus.OK.code())
                {
                    healthTargets.storeHealthyTarget(InetAddress.getByName(remoteAddress));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here `healthTargets.storeHealthyTarget` is just using HashSet to store the ip and healthTargets is a singleton class.

Comment: Thread bugs are bugs who that usually happen sporadic, and these bugs are usually hard to reproduce when they are reported, if you follow the rules of the interface regarding thread issues, you should be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share the same instance of the `Set` (which you seems to do) between different EventLoops you will run into issues. This is because the different Channels may run on different EventLoops and so Threads. This has the effect that you will need to make the access of `healthTargets` thread-safe.

This is not different to any other multi-threaded program.